# Unable to change favicon in PWA Vuex project

Tags: html, vuex, progressive-web-apps, setup-project, favicon

I've found the index.html and have tried removing the Vue-favicon and replacing it with my own. This does not work, and Vue's favicon keeps displaying. I have concluded the reason lies with me having chosen PWA and not SPA when setting up the project with Vue CLI 3.4.1.

I tried changing the favicon in the appropriate folder. Also tried removing the img-folder (that contains alot of vue's icons) that comes with the setup through vue-cli. Nothing worked.

`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">`

This is basically the code I have been looking at. Other than this, I don't know where to look. When I remove parts of the code, the favicon loads, but I get errors.

For example: `<link rel="icon" href="<>favicon.ico">`

With this, I do however get text showing on the top of the browser. If I remove `<>` as well, it defaults back to the Vue favicon, this I cannot explain.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Check this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708918/favicon-not-changing-in-vue-cli-project