# Favicon not changing in vue cli project

Tags: vue.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
  <title>Vue Router Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but vue-todo doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
      continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code of my `index.html` file in the `public` folder.
There is also an icon file named `favicon.ico`.
But when I run my dev server, the favicon is not showed.
Please help me.

I have tried to change

`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">`

to

`<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">`

but it's not working either.
and when i type `localhost:8080/favicon.ico`, it is showing my favicon.

Also, there are correct HTML tags when I debug on chrome dev tool.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
  <title>Vue Router Practice</title>
</head>
```

Expected result: favicon should be shown.

Answer (score 31):

I have a same problem.. but I success to fix this, when I switch the double quote to simple quote in the attribute *rel*, but I don't know why..

```
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

replace with:

```
    <link rel='icon' href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using PWA, check your `public/img/icons` folder too. And make sure that your `favicon-16x16.png` and `favicon-32x32.png` files are not the default ones.

And also best way to force cache is to hit the favicon address directly

`http://yourwebsite.com/favicon.ico`

and press `control+f5` for windows/linux or `shift+command+R` for Mac. You will see it changes. Then navigate back to your webpage and it will be refreshed.

Comment: Hitting the favicon address directly worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it seemed that Chrome was caching the favicon (was working on multiple projects at once). 
So a clear of the cache and closing the browser tab and restart is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had also created the project as a **PWA**, hence I also needed to change all the relevant icons

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue on a PWA project but clearing my cache fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you see one of the following calls in the network tab when requesting the icons,

```
img/icons/favicon.svg,
img/icons/favicon-32x32.png,
img/icons/favicon-16x16.png,
img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png,
img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg,
img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png
```

Do check if you are using the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` plugin which takes over the icon locations.

You should be able to override them by adding the following block to your `vue.config.js`

```
  pwa: {
    iconPaths: {
      faviconSVG: null,
      favicon32: 'favicon.ico',
      favicon16: 'favicon.ico',
      appleTouchIcon: null,
      maskIcon: null,
      msTileImage: null,
    },
  },
```

More info in their documentation: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#configuration